# wxWidget building problems

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, zlib

I've been trying to install and use wxWidgets v(2.8). I constantly run into the same issue. When building the wxWidgets libraries. I get this error:

error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zlib.h': No such file or directory  d:\wxwidgets-2.8.12\src\png\png.h   346

I can't work out why when I've installed it from the exe. I'm following the instructions from here: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B_Guide

I also get a Linker error which I don't think matters particularly.

Any help would be great. I've tried installing this from the exe and have also just use the zip folder but still run into the same issues. I suspect it might be something to do with environment variables but can't find a definitive answer whether they are required and what they should be set too.

EDIT
Also got something similar here:

error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'expat_config.h': No such file or directory  D:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\src\expat\lib\xmlparse.c    30
Cheers

Comment: 'the 20 projects' - Do you mean the sample projects?  Please post the error message.  BTW, since you are starting fresh, why not use v2.9?

Comment: @ravenspoint According to the link I provided you have to build the projects in the file wxWidgets-2.8.12\build\msw\wx.dsw and convert the projects to the lastest Visual Studio project. I chose 2.8 since I couldn't find any documentation on the 2.9 installation process which has a few extra projects. I'll edit the question with the error.

Comment: OK, those are the projects to build the libraries.

Comment: In my installation zlib.h is present in \wxWidgets-2.8.12\src.  You?

Comment: @ravenspoint I've got a zlib folder which then has zlib.h in so wxWidgets-2.18.12\src\zlib.

Comment: Oops, sorry, that is what I also have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With another install I managed to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In png.h at line 346 we have

```
/* include the compression library's header */
#include "zlib.h"
```

So you need to tell the compiler to look in  wxWidgets-2.18.12\src\zlib for headers.

Comment: It already does. In the additional directories, "..\..\src\zlib". Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: I should mention I've installed it at D:\wxWidgets-2.8.12\